# Rails - Avoid Repetition in Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have a table of data in which I go through each user attribute, and display it in a table. This seems like a lot of repetition, even though the words are not the same, the process for each attribute is. Is there a way to automatically make a table row with a header of `attribute.titleize` and a data cell of `user.attribute`?

```
%table
  %tr
    %th First Name
    %td= @user.first_name
  %tr
    %th Middle Name
    %td= @user.middle_name
  %tr
    %th Last Name
    %td= @user.last_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an `_attribute` partial to render a single row of the table:

```
# app/views/users/_attribute.html.haml
%tr
  %th= attribute.first.titleize
  %td= attribute.second

# app/views/users/show.html.haml
%table
  %tbody= render partial: 'attribute', collection: @user.attributes.to_a
```

If you don't want to render every attribute of `User`, create a method on the model that returns the attributes you do want and call that instead of `@user.attributes`:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User
  def public_attributes
    attributes.slice('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I never thought of using a partial in this fashion, still learning the collection aspect. I'll mark as answer when it allows me in a few minutes.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with an example of a method for selecting a subset of the attributes, if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a partial.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials